# How to redirect starting of app to home component if token is present

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to apply simple logic in my application where I want to skip login if the auth token is present in localStorage . I tried various ways but didn't happened.

If application browser/app get refreshes then also , I should able to redirect to home instead of login page.

**Service.ts**

```
//POST API for Login
  loginForm(data: any): Observable<RootObject> {
    return this.http
      .post<RootObject>(`${environment.baseUrl}/login`, data, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        tap((resp: RootObject) => this.setUser(resp.Result as Result)),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  setUser(resp: Result) {
    console.log(resp);
    this.authToken = resp.access_token;
    localStorage.setItem('username', JSON.stringify(resp.username));
    localStorage.setItem('access_token', JSON.stringify(resp.access_token));
    localStorage.setItem('expires_in', JSON.stringify(resp.expires_in));
    localStorage.setItem('userid', JSON.stringify(resp.userid));
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }

  // Checking if token is set
  isLoggedIn() {
    return localStorage.getItem('access_token') != null;
  }
```

**Auth guard:-**

```
canActivate()
    {
      if (!this.auth.isLoggedIn()) {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
  }
```

**Route-**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/login' }
];
```

Please suggest the solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create 2 different Guards for Login and Home components.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }, canActivate: [AuthGuard_2]
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard_1] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/login' }
];
```

**Auth_Guard_1:**

```js
canActivate()
    {
      if (this.auth.isLoggedIn()) {
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
  }
```

**Auth_Guard_2:**

```js
canActivate()
    {
      if (this.auth.isLoggedIn()) {
        return true;
      } else {
         this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
      }
  }
```

Comment: If manually I change the url to `/login` even if the token is present then I am able to see login page. I must restrict login page if token is present

Comment: Then you should change your AuthGuard to `/login`

Comment: I checked but this will show home component even if I remove the token from localStorage. If I delete token from local storage then it must navigate back to login on refresh

Comment: You are right. You need another `Guard` for HomeComponent.

Comment: Just create one more Guard, import it and use it. I updated my answer again.